# Char passing argument in c

Tags: c

Im writing a game in c and i want to change player in every step. So i create i function to do this.

```
struct Node{
    char player[4];
    int cubesRemaining;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
};

char *switchPlayer(struct Node *n){
    if (strcmp(n->player, "MAX") == 0){
        strcpy(n->player, "MIN");
        return (n->player);
    }
    else{
        strcpy(n->player, "MAX");
        return (n->player);
    }
}
```

Now i want to build the game tree and i create another function using recursion. Im also using the switchplayer function but im getting an error message.Here is my code:

```
struct Node *buildGameTree(int ncubes, char *player){
    struct Node *cube = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Node));
    cube->cubesRemaining = ncubes;
    strcpy(cube->player, player);

    if (cube->cubesRemaining >= 1){
        cube->left = buildGameTree(ncubes - 1, switchPlayer(cube->player));
    }
    if (cube->cubesRemaining >= M){
        cube->right = buildGameTree(ncubes - K, switchPlayer(cube->player));
    }

    return (cube);
}
```

The error message is: Warning passing argument 1 of switchplayer from incompatible pointer type

Comment: `switchPlayer(cube->player)` --> `switchPlayer(cube)`

Comment: Ask yourself the following questions: 1) what type arg does switchPlayer expect and 2) what are you passing in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `switchplayer` to take a `struct Node*` type, but you're passing `cube->player` which is a `char *`; therefore, you are passing an incompatible pointer type.

You probably want to just pass `cube` and not `cube->player` as in

```
cube->left = buildGameTree(ncubes -1, switchPlayer(cube));
```

Answer (score 2):

The function you've created receives an `struct Node *`. In your recursion you're passing the wrong parameter (`char *`), thus you might just change to `switchPlayer(cube)`

If you further allow me an observation, you must take care of all this recursive memory allocation (`calloc`), otherwise you'll end up with a big memory leak hole. :D